# #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class TextView

Tags: java, android, xml

I've been getting this error for a bit, and i'm not too sure what the cause of it is?. I've tried changing the xml file and the styles xml file, but have had no luck with it. I'm unsure what it means by class TextView?

XML file

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/waterRefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listofitems"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />



    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Empty List" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error Log

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.newView(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:106)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:252)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2389)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1878)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:705)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:766)
                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1687)
                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2191)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2697)
                                                                              at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16694)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5481)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2228)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1981)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1140)
                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6239)
                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                            at android.vie
```

Comment: SwipeRefreshLayout can only support one direct child.

Comment: oh okay, I've moved the textview out of the SwipeRefreshLayout, and i still get the problem?

Comment: I doubt it would help, but still it's better to be noted. `ListView` has too many attributes describing its height. After you moved `TextView` out of `SwipeRefreshLayout`, `android:layout_weight="1"` can be removed.

Comment: tbh forgot that was still there xD, thank you

Comment: The problem is with the item layout for your `ListView`'s `Adapter`.

Comment: I reinstalled the app, and it fixed the issue. @MIkeM. I will try that out, could you explain or know why this happened, its never happened before, it only happened when i started to change the colour and moved things around in the xml files?

Comment: I don't know the root cause of the Exception, since the stack trace is truncated. I was just telling you where to look from what I could read of the given trace. If reinstalling fixed it, it might've been an Instant Run glitch, or maybe you just needed a clean/rebuild.

Comment: oh okay, before i reinstalled it, i did clean/rebuild and resync several times and still had the problems.